# laravel update the selected value immediately and pass to the backend

Tags: ajax, laravel, request, laravel-blade, selection

hi I am working on a laravel project, I wanna have a selection, and the selected value updates and pass to the backend immediately once I choose a option value in the selection.
here is my markup:

```
<select name="survey_option" id="survey_option" class="flex space-x-3 items-center">
                                <option value="NoLink" disabled>Please select</option>
                                <option value="option1">option1</option>
                                <option value="option2">option2</option>
</select>
```

here is my script:

```
var $survey_option;

$(document).ready(function() {
                $('select[name=survey_option]').on('change', function() {
                    survey_option = $(this).val();
                    console.log(survey_option);
                });
            });

var datatable = $('#label-record-table').on('xhr.dt', function ( e, settings, json, xhr ) {
        }).DataTable({
            ajax:{
                url:"xxxxxx",
                type:"POST",
                dataType:"JSON",
                data: function (d) {
                    d.selected_label = survey_option;
                }
            },
            columns:[
                {data: xxxx},
            ]
        });
```

here is my backend code:

```
$selected_label = $request->survey_option;
```

the current result is that: the selected value in ui can update immediately, but the selected value passed to the backend (`selected_label`) cannot update immediately. can you please help me figure it out? Many THX!

Comment: you are not reloading your datatable after the survey_option has changed!?

Comment: @krisgjika i think that's the reason, but I don't know how to reload the datatable after the survey_option value changed

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()

Answer (score 0):

According to the issue you have described, I suppose what you are trying to achieve is - showing the results on the page when you make selections within a given SELECT list in real-time basis. Please correct me if I am wrong.

If this is right, then I have mentioned 02 ways you can solve this issue.

**Version 01**
The feature you are trying to build works well with SPA - single page applications that has integrated State Management technology such as REDUX or VUEX but, if you are trying to achieve this in Laravel with AJAX, then the Process Speed will be longer for each click since the AJAX call will process reading each data record and passing updates. Recommended way to build this feature would be using a submit button with AJAX form submission.

**Version 02**
I noticed your AJAX code has not been properly written. I will leave below the right code along with your requirements. Make sure you have jQuery v3.7 or later imported as well.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var survey_option;
  
  $('select[name=survey_option]').on('change', function() {
    survey_option = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '{{ route('xxx_ROUTE_NAME_HERE_xxx') }}',
      data: survey_option,
      success: function(data) {
          // Handle the success response load 
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        // Handle any errors here
        console.error('AJAX Error:', status, error);

        console.error('Response Text:', xhr.responseText);

      };
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<select name="survey_option" id="survey_option" class="flex space-x-3 items-center">
  <option value="NoLink" disabled>Please select</option>
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: datatable will do the ajax call by itself, all you have to do it tell it to reload the data with the updated `survey_option`. This solution ignores the existence of the datatable.